# Upload file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I guys I read the documentation for do a upload file in laravel...  But I don't understand more it (I'm beginner) 
It's my image.blade.php

```
{{Form::open(['url'=>'administrator/store ', 'files' => true])}} 
{!!Form::file('image') !! } 
{!! Form::submit('next')!!} 
{{Form::close()}}
```

Administrator Controller

```
use Storage; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; 

public function store(Request $request) {
Storage::put($request->image, 'test') ;
}
```

I don't understand what I will put into the function..... Help me pls...
Greetings!

Comment: what is the real question?

Comment: I don't understand how I will do upload my file after I link it by the form... What I will do insert into the function for take and upload the file? These I write into the fuction  doesn't work!

Comment: These what, and define "doesn't work".

Comment: After the Storage::put the file doesn't store into the path "Storage/app/test"

Comment: https://youtu.be/Q6iL3u4IZgs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\Illuminate\Http\Request::file()` is what you have when you're uploading files.

This is just a instance of [\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html) class so you can [move](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.php#L92) file to destination/storage what you want, something like that:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        /**
         * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile
         */
        $uploadedFile = $request->file('image'); 
        
        if ($uploadedFile->isValid()) {
            $uploadedFile->move(destinationPath, $fileName);
        }
    }

}
```

Aso, you've been used `\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::put()` in a wrong way. Below is like that method is implemented:

```
/**
     * Write the contents of a file.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  string  $contents
     * @param  bool  $lock
     * @return int
     */
    public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false)
    {
        return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_EX : 0);
    }
```