# Request doesn't get uploaded file in Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, file-upload, controller, laravel-8

I am working on a project using Laravel 8, and whenever I try to upload the image, I send the request as an object to save it. It doesn't have the image that I uploaded. I am not sure if the problem lies in my code or if other files are corrupted. Please take a look.

**View**

```
<form action="/profilephoto/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="photopath" value="{{ Auth::user()->profilephoto }}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="submit" value="Done">
            {{-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button> --}}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function fileUploadPost(Request $request)
{
    return $request;

    if (! file_exists($request->uid)) {
        File::makeDirectory($request->uid);
    }
    if (file_exists($request->uid.'/profile')) {
        File::deleteDirectory($request->uid.'/profile');
    }
    File::makeDirectory($request->uid.'/profile');
    $path = $request->image->store($request->uid.'/profile');

    DB::table('users')->where('id', $request->uid)->update([
        'profilephoto' => 'storage/'.$path,
    ]);

    return back()->with('success', 'You have successfully upload image.');
}
```

Comment: You have a return right at the beginning in your method. Everything after that won't be executed.

Comment: `file_exists($request->uid)` I'm pretty sure that's not what you want to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload file in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239049/upload-file-in-laravel)

Comment: Read Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#files They are pretty straight forward and easy to understand - you can get a good foundation for the basics from Laravel docs.

Comment: Check if you are uploading a file that surpasses the values for "post_max_size" and "upload_max_size" in your php.ini. Try and see if a very small image works